# Trouble constructing an object with data in a text file using commas as delimiters

Tags: java, text-files, java.util.scanner

I'm having trouble creating an Inventory object through a constructor that is reading from a txt file.

This is the file:

```
1165,4.25,15
1305,1.80,42
1345,12.56,16
1388,7.42,30
1480,6.54,80
1495,8.36,48
1560,15.27,65
```

So I'm attempting to grab the "1165" into the first variable then "4.25" into the next, etc. So the comma is the delimiter. When I run my program it throws an exception after the first time through the while loop in main and the variables are just being assigned "1", "1.0", and "6" instead of getting the entirety of the numbers.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Proj2 {
    public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException {

        Scanner soldScan;
        Scanner invScan;

        soldScan = new Scanner (new File("SoldSorted.txt"));
        invScan = new  Scanner (new File("Inventory.txt"));
        invScan = invScan.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile(",|\\s*"));
        int count =0;
        while (soldScan.hasNext()){

            Sales x = new Sales(soldScan.next());
            Inventory y = new Inventory(invScan.nextInt(),invScan.nextDouble(),invScan.nextInt());

            x.printSales();
            y.printInv();
            count++;
        }
        for (int i=0;i<count;i++){

        }

    }
}
public class Inventory {
    int productCode;
    double price;
    int quantityOnHand;

    public Inventory(int code, double cost, int inStock) {
        productCode = code;
        price = cost;
        quantityOnHand = inStock;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        productCode = code;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setInStock(int inStock) {
        quantityOnHand = inStock;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return productCode;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public int getInStock() {
        return quantityOnHand;
    }

    public int postSale(int sold) {
        quantityOnHand = quantityOnHand - sold;
        return quantityOnHand;
    }

    public void printInv(){
        System.out.println("Product Code: " + productCode);
        System.out.println("Price: " + price);
        System.out.println("Quantity on Hand: " + quantityOnHand);
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
Product Code: 1165
Quantity Sold: 24
Product Code: 1
Price: 1.0
Quantity on Hand: 6

Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
    at Proj2.main(Proj2.java:18)
```

Comment: Hint: 1165 is char by char 1, 1 (or 1.0), 6 and 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a bug in the regex. * is the wildcard for 0 or more matches so "`,|\\s*`" will match the empty string. Try "`,|\\s+`".